# Angular directive not picking up service data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angular-ui-router

My service NavData

```
angular.module('navData', []).
    factory('NavData', function() {
        var navData = {};
        navData.depth = 0;
        navData.category_id = "";
        navData.category_name = "";
        navData.subcategory_id = "";
        navData.subcategory_name = "";
        return navData;
    });
```

receives values from ui-router on some pages:

```
  var category = { 
    name: 'category',
    parent: site,
    url: '/categories/:category_id',
    onEnter: function(NavData, $stateParams){
      NavData.depth = 1;
      NavData.category_id = $stateParams.category_id;
      console.log(NavData);         
    },
    views: {
      'navigation': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/category-menu.html'
      },
      'content': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/category-images.html'
      }
    }
  };
```

A directive, appearing on all pages, should watch for changes in the service and reflect them in a custom breadcrumb function:

```
  .directive('breadcrumb', ['NavData', function(NavData){
    return {
      templateUrl: 'partials/breadcrumb.html',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){
        scope.depth            = NavData.depth;
        scope.category_id      = NavData.category_id;
        scope.category_name    = NavData.category_name;
        scope.subcategory_name = NavData.subcategory_name;

        var doStuff = function(navdata){
          console.log("watching depth: " + navdata.depth);
          console.log("watching cat_id: "+ navdata.category_id);
        };
        scope.$watch(NavData.depth, doStuff(NavData), true);
        scope.$watch(NavData.category_id, doStuff(NavData), true);
      }

    };
  }])
```

However, scope.$watch seems not to work. This is my log:

```
watching depth: 0 directives.js:28
watching cat_id:  directives.js:29
watching depth: 0 directives.js:28
watching cat_id:  directives.js:29
Object {depth: 1, category_id: "1", category_name: "", subcategory_id: "", subcategory_name: ""} app.js:25
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to $watch the scope.deth and not the factory ?

Comment: I just tried, but no difference. (Not that I would expect it: why?)

Comment: will be fine if you have fiddler or Plunker

Comment: Do you mean that this works on fiddler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first error is in the `scope.$watch()` 1st argument: It is either an expression (string) evaluated in the given `scope`, or a function returning a value; the value is stored and the function is run on every digest cycle; if the new value is different, the listener (2nd argument) is triggered.

So the first correction is:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return NavData.depth,
}, .../*other arguments, see below*/);
```

Now the 2nd argument is wrong as well! It is expected to be a *function*, you are providing the *returned value of a function* (which, by the way, is undefined for `doStuff`). This 2nd argument function receives the new value (as returned by the 1st argument above), the old value and the scope. In your case you don't care about the new/old value. So the complete solution should be:

```
scope.$watch(function() { // decide the watched value
    return NavData.depth,
}, function() { // what to do when the value changes
    // do stuff and reference NavData normally
});
```

Comment: thanks! for some reason i didn't know you could pass a function as the 1st argument

Comment: I set my own directive up this way but the watcher is only called once? `scope.$watch ()-> return myFactory.aVariable, 
    ()->
     console.log myFactory.aVariable`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `NavData` only changes by `ui-router` `onEnter` callbacks, you could possibly skip the whole `NavData` object and `$watch` implementation.

Simply broadcast an event on every `onEnter` callback:

```
onEnter: function($rootScope, $stateParams){
   $rootScope.$broadcast("NavDataChanged", {
       depth: 1,
       category_id: $stateParams.category_id
       /* (any other former NavData properties) */
   });
}
```

And your directive would become:

```
.directive('breadcrumb', [function(){
    return {
      templateUrl: 'partials/breadcrumb.html',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){
        scope.$on("NavDataChanged", function(event, navData) {
            scope.depth = navData.depth;
            scope.category_id = navData.category_id;
            // any other former NavData properties and doStuff code
        });
      }
    };
  }])
```

Simplified version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dT6V4/1/).